# Can I copy / mirror data AND formatting from one main sheet to a secondary sheet? If so, how?

Tags: repeat, mirroring

I have been tracking student progress in one spreadsheet and have formatted it for easy viewing and student comprehension (when sharing the data with them in one-on-one meetings). Basically, I use colours and various line weights.

I would like to continue to have my main sheet, with all of my students data, but then create separate sheets for each student student where their data can be viewed on an individual basis. An individual sheet would be more direct for the student and also increase privacy for other students.

I am aware that I can copy basic data over to another sheet using a code like this: MainSheet!F6:F20. This unfortunately only brings over the data. If I copy and paste my formatting into the sheet and then add this code, it works but is easy to break if I adjust anything in the sheet. In the end, all I want is to simply mirror the columns that are assigned to each student into their own separate sheet WITH formatting.

Thank you so much, this has been driving me crazy. If it is not possible, I genuinely think that Google needs to do something about this for many people are asking this same question online.

I answer this in my first response. Research online, trying a code like this ( MainSheet!F6:F20 ), manually coding each box (nightmare).